# Do quasi-isometric groups have the same rational cohomology?

Tags: group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two finitely generated groups which are quasi-isometric in the sense of geometric group theory.

Are their rational cohomology rings $H^{\ast}(G_i; \mathbb Q)$ necessarily isomorphic?

Comment: For finitely generated *nilpotent* groups the answer is positive by work of Shalom and Sauer.

Comment: The infinite dihedral group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are quasi-isometric, so Yves' observation does not hold for virtually nilpotent groups.

Comment: It's not an "observation" but a deep theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, $F_2$ is quasi-isometric to $F_3$ because the latter is finite index in the former, but their rational $H^1$s differ.

Comment: And here is a machine for producing lots of counterexamples. Let $F$ be a finitely generated group on which a finite group $G$ acts. Then $H^{\bullet}(F \rtimes G, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H^{\bullet}(F, \mathbb{Q})^G$, but $F$ is finite index in $F \rtimes G$ so again they are quasi-isometric.

Comment: Ian Agol's example in the comments can be obtained by taking $F = \mathbb{Z}$ and $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$ acting by $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

No. Any two groups acting properly and cocompactly by isometries on the same locally compact space $X$ are quasi-isometric to $X$ and hence to each other (Milnor-Svarc Lemma).

For example all fundamental groups of closed hyperbolic $3$-manifolds are quasi-isometric to hyperbolic 3-space. But not all closed hyperbolic 3-manifolds have the same rational cohomology.

Comment: For a survey on quasi-isometric rigidity questions (and in particular positive answers in some special cases) see http://www.math.utah.edu/pcmi12/lecture_notes/kapovich.pdf